# How to restore Gnome desktop environment in Debian 6?

Tags: gnome, debian-squeeze, desktop-environments

After installing Meld in Debian 6, the whole OS became desktopless after I restarted. How do I restore the Gnome desktop? Currently my full screen is on command prompt mode.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use the command `startx` or you can check the file `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`. It should say something like: `/usr/sbin/gdm3` or `/usr/sbin/kdm`.